# Why does pandas treat datetime indexes differently for multiplication?

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas multiplication doesn't work as I'd expect for column dataframes:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3]})

In [3]: s = pd.Series([5,6,7])

In [4]: df * s

    0   1   2   a
0 NaN NaN NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN NaN NaN
2 NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

As discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642162/python-divide-each-row-of-a-dataframe-by-another-dataframe-vector), the correct approach is to [specify the axis](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.multiply.html):

```
In [5]: df.multiply(s, axis='index')

    a
0   5
1  12
2  21
```

However, this is unnecessary for dataframes with datetime indexes:

```
In [6]: import numpy as np

In [7]: days = np.arange('2000-12-20', '2000-12-23', dtype='datetime64[D]')

In [8]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3]}, index=days)

In [9]: s = pd.Series([5,6,7], index=days)

In [10]: df * s

             a
2000-12-20   5
2000-12-21  12
2000-12-22  21
```

Why is this? Why doesn't the first example work, and is it possible to always use `*` rather than `.multiply`?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like that is older deprecated behavior.  Issue [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2304).  Probably best to be explicit in both cases.

```
In [161]: pd.__version__
Out[161]: '0.16.2'

In [160]: df * s
....: FutureWarning: TimeSeries broadcasting along DataFrame index by default is deprecated. Please use DataFrame.<op> to explicitly broadcast arithmetic operations along the index
  FutureWarning)
Out[160]: 
             a
2000-12-20   5
2000-12-21  12
2000-12-22  21
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your other question, you can probably use `*` instead of `.multiply` in the vast majority of cases (maybe all) but whether or not that's an improvement may be a different question.  You are probably best off thinking of operators as convenient shortcuts to `add`, `sub`, etc., but that are not always the best approach.

Regardless, if you do want to use `*` here you could do any of the following:

```
df['a'] * s                    # convert df to series

df * pd.DataFrame(s).values    # convert s to dataframe then to array

df * s.values.reshape(3,1)     # convert s to numpy array
```

The first one is pretty obvious, you just set things up so that both are series and then things behave as you'd like.  And note that this is easier than converting both to dataframes in that you only need the indexes (axis=0) to align when multiplying series, but you need both indexes and columns (axis=1) to align when multiplying dataframes.  Though you could get around this here by giving your series the same name as the dataframe column you wish to multiply by.

The second and third ways are more interesting and general.  They get rid of the index by converting to a numpy array.  Doing it this way frees you up to do lots of different things but keep in mind that it can be dangerous since you are explicitly ignoring the indexes, meaning it's up to you to make sure they are correctly lined up.

Also note that in general you can use `.values.shape` to get a better idea of what dimensions are when you're trying to multiply, divide, etc.  Often when these operations fail, a quick check of the shape will show you why.