# How to divide one data frame to another completely

Tags: python, pandas

Consider two dataframes like:

`df1`:

```
   A   B   C   D
x  1   2   3   4
y  5   6   7   8
```

`df2`:

```
   A   B   C   D
x  2   4   2   5
y  3   2   4   8
```

How do I divide `df1` with `df2` and get a result like this?

```
   A     B   C      D
x  .5   .5   1.5   .8
y  1.6   3   1.75   1
```

Comment: And `df1/df2` doesn't work for you?

Comment: It gives NaN values on all the columns

Answer (score 1):

Then just try

```
out = df1.div(df2)
```

For more information about how to divide two dataframes, please refer to https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html

There are also other posts on Stack Overflow that you can refer to:

[Divide a dataframe by another dataframe according to index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44466121/divide-a-dataframe-by-another-dataframe-according-to-index)

[Python: Divide each row of a DataFrame by another DataFrame vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642162/python-divide-each-row-of-a-dataframe-by-another-dataframe-vector)

Comment: I am getting all the NaN values and the number of rows has doubled

Comment: I found the right answer:  out = df1.div(df2.values)